# windows authentication issue on server but not from local pc

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization, windows-authentication

I have my c# asp.net web application set up for windows authentication.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> <!-- Denies access to the anonymous user. -->
        </authorization>
```

I have 2 issues.

Firstly, if I navigate to my site from my local PC, I get asked for a username/password to which I enter the credentials I use to log on to the server and these are successful and I gain access. However if I navigate to the site on the server via the internet browser, I get asked for the credentials to which I supply same - but it never lets me access, keep getting pop up to re enter my credentials. Any ideas why this might be so? Do I have incorrect configuration?

Secondly, is it possible to set up windows authentication when access the site from my local PC asking for username/password, but when accessing it on the server, I am not asked for such and can access the site without providing any details?

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected "Integrated Windows Authentication" in the IIS for your web site?

What mode you have for the authentication in your web.config?

Comment: Yes I have selected "Integrated Windows Authentication". My web.config setting is -> <authentication mode="Windows" />

Comment: do you supply your domain name when providing username / password from outside of your network?